# What should I do after I finish writing my novel?

Tags: creative-writing, publishing, first-draft

A few days ago I started writing the first draft of my current novel project. I was wondering  what should I do with it when I'm done.

Comment: You have a long way to go but good job to be motivated! What is your pupose: personal edification, self publishing, or commercial publication? It is OK to write your first book just to prove you can do it. It's a marathon, and you will be a much better writer at the end for book 2 and beyond.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put it in a drawer for a month or three. Pull it out, re-read it, mark up problems, and fix them. Then hand it off to an editor. Implement those edits. Lather, rinse, repeat as necessary.

At that point you'll need to decide if you want to publish it. If so, you can either self-publish or hire an agent to try to find you a publisher.

Comment: As a side question, should one send the script to a beta reader before or after the editor has cracked down on it? (Assuming of course that one is using beta readers.)

Comment: I usually do beta readers before. There are 2 kinds of editing: line editing and scene editing. The beta readers are for scenes (which should go?). After those changes, you are ready for line editing: word choice, sentence structure, grammar, and punctuation. This is expensive. I would recommend a reputable style guide and dictionary and do as much as you can yourself.

Comment: I don't know at all what beta readers are?

Comment: @WritingNerd A beta reader is basically someone you send your manuscript to, who will then 'proofread' it for free. As I understand the term, they are generally friends or colleagues willing to lend you their opinion. They do not take the place of a professional editor.

Comment: @tommymyron Oh OK.Do you know any beta readers because I dont

Comment: I'm about 5 short on my last book (10 is a nice round number) if you'd like to trade. harryagold72@gmail.com (I know this site isn't about self promotion ...)

Comment: @WritingNerd I believe beta readers are personal acquaintances, so I can't really offer you any leads in that department. I would see if any of your friends are willing to give your manuscript a thorough read-through and offer un-biased criticism.